# How do I query navigation properites using linq to sql and ef

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, objectcontext

I am trying to **strongly type** a query for 3 ef objects using linq to sql. There are one-to-many relationships with product and category.  My classes contain navigation properties and look like this.

```
public partial class Product
{

public int ID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Group> NpGroup {get;set;}
}

public partial class Category
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Group> NpGroup {get;set;}
}

public partial class Group
{
public int ID {get;set;}
public int ProductID {get;set;}
public int CategoryID {get;set;}
public virtual Product NpProduct {get;set;}
public virtual Category NpCategory {get;set;}
}
```

Trying to avoid the string based .Include(), how would I construct a query that returned a group equal to ProductID "1" but also included the names of the product and category?

Something like:

```
var context = ObjectContext.CurrentObjectContext;
    var query = from c in context.Group
    where c.ProductID == 1
    //Include the names of the product and category of the group record (c.NpProduct.Name etc.)
    select c;
```

I am probably missing the trees through the forest but I can not seem to get the syntax of ObjectContext.LoadProperty (if that is the right way to go).

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i doubt you are using **both** L2SQL and EF, so try not to confuse people.

Anyways, with EF - there is two ways to load the navigational properties:

1 - Eager Loading

```
q.Include("NavPropertyName")
```

2 - Explicit Load

```
*After* running your above query - use q.NavPropertyName.Load()
```

Difference is option 2) causes 2 queries, option 1 causes an inner join on the FK.

I can sympathise with your reluctance to use Include because of the 'magic strings' - i'm not sure why the EF team didn't make them strongly typed, however im sure there was a good reason.

More info on Load/Include [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896249.aspx).

HTH

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions and I think my problem is my return type of List<T>.  In my above example what I am trying to get is each product and its properties from the ('mapping like') group object reference.  Do I need to use some sort of foreach loop?  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Well yes, your above query is `select c` - c is an alias in your query for a `Group`. It's just an IQueryable, i assume you are doing .ToList at the end, which will project the query into a `List<Group>`. You need to change the projection to what you want returned. If you want Products, select from Products, not Group (as your doing in your query).

Answer (score 0):

I think we all hate to use the typed string in the .include() statement.

I've started to use a enum to represent the table name, just to avoid spelling errors, etc.

for my database of about 70 tables it took me 10 min. to create the enum and my linq is now something like this:

var context = ObjectContext.CurrentObjectContext;
    var query = from c in context.Group.Include(TableEnum.Category.ToString())
    where c.ProductID == 1
    select c;

Again, not perfect, but at least it's checked by the compiler

Comment: I didn't frame my question very well.  I was trying to keep it simple.  What I really was trying to get were

Comment: Yep im doing the same thing as @Furnes - i pass through an [] of enums to my service layer. I then use an extension method to convert this to a series of .Includes.